# How can I get UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

How can I get UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM, I am not clear that how does it work, can anyone please guide me?

Comment: do u mean code? or want to understand the concept

Answer (score 3):

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    // iPad device
} else {
    // iPhone / iPod touch device
}
```

From the Apple Header files:

```
/* The UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() macro is provided for use when deploying to a version of the iOS less than 3.2. If the earliest version of iPhone/iOS that you will be deploying for is 3.2 or greater, you may use -[UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom] directly. */
#define UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] ? [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] : UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```